# PHP IF Else Function Not Working

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a problem, I can't get the result of my code. When I try to debug the code. I using IF statement in my code.

It's just simple, example : if kelas(based on user_id login) = 1, then redirect it to kelas1.php, if kelas = 2, the redirect to kelas 2, else no have a kelas.

Here it's my code :

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {      
    header('Location: form_login_siswa.html');
}
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
include ("config.php");
$query = "SELECT kelas FROM t_siswa WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
$hasil = mysql_query($query);

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)) {
    $kelas = $data['kelas'];

    if($kelas = 1) {
        include ("kelas1.php");
    }
    if($kelas = 2) {
        include ("kelas2.php");
    } else {
        echo "Tidak ada kelas";
    }
}
?>
```

Anyone, please help to solve the problem.
Appreciated with your helps.

Thank you.

Comment: You should probably start by reading [the language reference portion of the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php). If you're not comfortable using conditionals yet, then it's very likely that there are other fundamentals of the PHP language you're also insufficiently versed in, and this will seriously impede any other efforts you make to advance your knowledge if you don't have your foundations set. Also, format your code neatly. Find a standard coding style and follow it. Otherwise, it's going to make debugging problems in your code very difficult and introduce errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($kelas = 1)
```

should be

```
if($kelas == 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing an `else` and also not using the correct operator for comparison.

Also, switch around the comparison so that the first value is always a valid value.

```
if(1 == $kelas)
{
    include ("kelas1.php");
}
else if(2 == $kelas)
{
    include ("kelas2.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Tidak ada kelas";
}
```

Comment: or use `switch` and `case`, the same effect

Comment: Switching the comparison is not necessary. It only prevents you from making an error because 1 = $kelas will throw an error.

Comment: yea, but i mean if you have 1 variable and many options, you can use `switch` and `case` to check all values rather than `elseif` or `else if`. But both ways give the same effect.

Comment: I've tried the code, but still not working... when I debug the code, nothing change.

Comment: what does "not working" mean? Is your code printing "Tidak ada kelas" all the time? Check what is in the $data variable if the results are not what you're expecting them to be.

Comment: $data function is to get kelas data, What I want to do is, If user kelas 1 (in database) then, it will redirect to page kelas1.php, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
$kelas = 1
```

is assignment

```
$kelas == 1
```

is comparison

Answer (score 1):

Try using == instead of = . The "=" is an assignment operator and the expression gets the value of the right operand.

```
if($kelas == 1)
{
    include ("kelas1.php");
}
if($kelas == 2)
{
    include ("kelas2.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Tidak ada kelas";
}
```

Also, the statement will always `echo "Tidak ada kelas";` if `($kelas == 1)`. Was this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

In your if statements using `==` for testing comparison rather than single `=` which is for assignment

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [elsif structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)) {
  $kelas = $data['kelas'];

  if($kelas == 1) {
    include ("kelas1.php");
  } elseif($kelas == 2) {
    include ("kelas2.php");
  } else {
    echo "Tidak ada kelas";
  }
}
```

Or the [switch structure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)) {
  switch($data['kelas']){
    case 1:
      include ("kelas1.php");
      break;
    case 2:
      include ("kelas2.php");
      break;
    default:
    echo "Tidak ada kelas";
  }
}
```

Comment: can you check by echoing in each condition,just to check in which condition it is going ? @user1473757